# how to get feed from feedBurner

Tags: android, xml, feed

I want to make an android rss feed reader app. but the websites are not giving xml file for the feed. i have found some rss links from feedBurner i.e "#   http://feeds.feedburner.com/EXAMPLE_SITE #". I have no idea how to get feed except Parsing xml.
is there any better idea or how i get feed xml url?

I tried some web service to convert url to rss . but its too complex because  tag contains all html tags and attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Just add "?format=xml" on your link, and you are ready !

```
http://feeds.feedburner.com/EXAMPLE_SITE?format=xml
```

Comment: It works for me ... try to execute this on linux/mac 
    curl -s 'feeds.feedburner.com/techtunes?format=xml'

Comment: It is a valid XML file, what do you see doing this request ?

Comment: view-source:http://feeds.feedburner.com/techtunes?format=xml
worked !

but description tag containing too much html tags, I want a fresh HTML text into my text View
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(SourceSting), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

Displays the html tags